# How to check if there is an update in Android OS using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to check if there is a software update in Android OS from Flutter side. Is there any package that helps me to do that?

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [upgrader](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader) for this

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Upgrader Example',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Upgrader Example')),
          body: UpgradeAlert(
            child: Center(child: Text('Checking...')),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to check if there is a newer version of the operating system, not the application.

Comment: got you, alright, searching for packages I can't find any to make sure there is a system update, sorry

Comment: Anyone have example showing how to use "onLater" function of Upgrader?